# how to download from array of bytes as string in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an api which returns array of bytes for downloading a pdf file.

So when i read the api,

i have a format as below

```
{
  "data": "string",
  "errors": [
    "string"
  ],
  "isSuccessData": true,
  "success": true,
  "statusCode": 0,
  "message": "string"
}
```

Where 'data' is the array of bytes, which is coming as string in my angular side.

How can i download/view pdf from the data above?

so what i tried is

```
  downloadPdf(id: string) {
        var x = new IdRequest();
        x.id = id;
        this.listingService.getPdf(x).subscribe(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                console.log("data", response.data)
                var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                let pdfContent = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open(pdfContent, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
            }
        })
    }
```

But the file is showin as error.... How to fix it?

Comment: Why would you create the file from client-side ? It's better to do it from server-side and then send the file itself

Comment: i have a list of bytearrays (need to implement multiple download)

Comment: Is response an ArrayBuffer?

Comment: return types is byte[] from my weba api, in angular its coming as string